# Continuous looping while in java

Tags: java

This simple code snippet doesn't work. I want to type 10 input and jump out of `while` loop and calculate average but it doesn't jump out of `while` loop.

Following is my code:

```
    double total = 0;
    double average;
    int grade;
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(counter < 10) {
        grade = input.nextInt();
        total += grade;
        counter++;
    }
    average = total / 10;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, average);
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: That loop works fine and will run exactly 10 times. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @sina, what was the problem/solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no issues with this code. If you can't see the JOptionPane, try minimizing all of your windows as it may have appeared behind them.

Also, it's probably better to use a for loop in this situation, rather than a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't let you jump out of the loop when the user enters 10 is because you have an entirely separate variable controlling when you exit the loop. The `counter` variable, which is incrementing by one each iteration, controls when you exit the loop. Thus, you will always exit the loop after 10 iterations. To fix this so that you exit the loop when the user enters 10, make your exit condition dependent on `grade`, not `counter`, like so:

```
while(grade != 10){
    grade = input.nextInt();
    if(grade != 10)
        total += grade;
}
```

Just a side note: When accepting user input, you should tell the user what you expect, so they don't enter something that you don't expect, and are able to follow your instructions.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP said that the loop continued infinitely instead of stopping after 10 iterations.

Comment: I thought about that, but judging by the words he uses in the question ("I want to type 10 and break out of the while loop"), I think he expects it to break out immediately, and is confused as to why it doesn't.

Comment: The key word is type, as in he wants the user to type 10 and break out of the while loop.

Comment: @adeen-s exactly . it doesnt stop

Comment: @sina I'm pretty sure I solved it, take a look. If I'm wrong about what you wanted, though, you should edit the question so it's more clear to the readers.

Comment: I think that since average is calculated by dividing the total by 10, it implies that the user needs to enter 10 numbers.

Comment: @SteveSmith  You might be right, but I'm going to leave this up just in case.